# C#: Stop a background thread (ThreadPool/WaitCallback)

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I'm using the following code to create a background thread that handles a data importer. This way, the users of my application can still see the UI updates (it's not frozen).

```
public void StartImport()
{
    //Start the background thread that performs the import
    ImportThread importThread = new ImportThread(this);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(importThread.ImportData));
}
```

However, I'm having a bad time trying to create a function to stop this background task (called from a Stop Import button). Since the import function is complex, using a bool variable to control if it is still valid and stop it when it is false does not work for me. Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: Well, you really should use a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-6.0) instead of a bool, but the principle is the same. The function needs to check to see if it should continue from time to time. If that approach doesn't work for you I suggest you share why, so folks on this forum can help. But the alternative-- aborting the thread from outside-- is almost never a good idea.

Comment: See [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads).